# Simplemodal closing when I use CustomValidator server side validation in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, simplemodal, customvalidator

I'am building an asp.net application that have a gridview inside an update pannel.

In this grid, I added a command field that raise a server event to fill fields on my modal popup hiden div section, show the modal for the the user and wait.

The user is editing the fields and click save.

Linked to these fields I have several Validation control.  some are standard, same are custom.

When my customValidator are using client side script, everything is goiing fine; if one field is invalide, the summary section is displayed and the modal for still visible.

But ... (cause without a but I won't have to writte this question)

When my CustomValidator is a server side validation, even if it fail, the modal form is closed and my save button even is raised.

I use a CustomValidator because that validation need a real time database verification.

my issue is : how may I make this server side validation keeping the modal popup open if it return false (e.isvalid = false) ?

If this is not possible .. i tried to call the :  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((Control)sender, sender.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "$('#basic-modal-content-province').modal({appendTo:'form', persist:true});", true);

but it did not work -> it say that $ is not defined

I use http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

I am totally new to JQuery and AJAX, thanks for your help

Steph

Comment: hummm ... I was not expecting that this was a big question ...

more than 30 readings and nobody provide an idea of the issue.

If you don't have an idea of what I should do to fix this, do you have an idea of want i could do as workarround ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the custom validator with the AJAX modal extender and then once you submit the data in the modal check to see if there are errors by checking if the page is valid, if not valid then make the extender show using it’s show() function - for example with c#:

```
protected void btnExampleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        //Logic to submit if valid
    }
    else
    {
        //If there are errors then keep the modal open
        btnOpenModal_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
    }
}
```

Outside of that I'm not sure there's any other way to keep the modal open with the custom validator since it doesn't post back.